# Unmet peer dependencies for react-firebase-file-uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Trying to install, have updated firebase and react to these exact versions. Using npm version 4.1.2 - any thoughts?

```
npm install -g react-firebase-file-uploader
/usr/local/lib

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase@^3.5.2

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^15.3.2

└── react-firebase-file-uploader@2.4.1

npm WARN react-firebase-file-uploader@2.4.1 requires a peer of firebase@^3.5.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-firebase-file-uploader@2.4.1 requires a peer of react@^15.3.2 but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install `react-firebase-file-uploader` globally, I suppose you need to install it for your project and in which case you want it to be a dependency. Install it like

```
npm install -S react-firebase-file-uploader
```

Also make sure you have `firebase@^3.5.2` and `react@^15.3.2` installed